# How to get rid of eslint prettier errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslintrc, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

How do I get rid of this replace error that underline red all over my code?
Also everytime I "fix" all the errors, whenever I save, it show me the same error again.

[image: How do I get rid of this replace error that underline red all over mny]

Comment: Have you tried replacing 8 spaces by 4 spaces (or whatever it means that it is complaining about)? Have you tried clicking on "Quick Fix"?

Comment: disable eslint, just like I did

Comment: I added new information about it, but yeah the thing is I fix it and then I save and all the same underline shit

Comment: I don't want to disable it, since I am a learner in Javascript, I installed it to get better at good practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by unistalling JS-CSS-HTML Formatter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to "**Configure Default Formatter**" to Prettier and "**Format document**" :).

[image: Format Document With]

[image: Configure Default Formatter]

[image: Select extension]

[image: Format Document]

[image: Done]